# Почему программа скомпилированная при помощи Clang и GCC ведет себя по-разному?

Tags: c, gcc, clang

Вопрос к знатокам компиляторов Clang и GCC.
  Сложилась следующая ситуация. Придумал реализацию функции swap на языке C без использования дополнительной переменной и в одну строку. И столкнулся вот с чем: если компилировать исходник, используя gcc, то программа не работает, так как я планировал, но если скомпилировать посредством Clang, то программа работает, как задумывалось, то есть меняет значения местами.

Код в исходнике "prog.c":

```
#include <stdio.h>

void SWAP(int *a, int *b) {
        *b = *a + ((*a = *b) - *a);
}

int main() {
        int a = 5, b = 6;
        printf("%d %d\n", a, b);
        SWAP(&a, &b);
        printf("%d %d\n", a, b);

        return 42;
}
```

Компилирую при помощи gcc: "gcc -o prog prog.c" - получаю: a и b равны 6.
Компилирую при помощи clang: "clang -o prog prog.c" - значения a и b меняются местами.
Собственно, хотел бы поподробнее узнать, почему так происходит

Comment: Потому что Undefined Behavior.

Comment: По факту, здесь весь вопрос что будет раньше, *a = *b или *a закинется в во временную переменную. Раньше это точкой следования назыали, сейчас чуть иначе но принцип такой. А если коротко - есть проще методы.

Comment: В таком случае интересно узнать, как заранее знать как поведет себя компилятор. Насколько я понял ответ @pavel , то порядок выполнения операций зависит от компилятор, но ведь есть приоритет операций и по сути порядок выполнения должен быть строго определен на уровне языка. Это "знание" достается изучением документации на компилятор ?

Comment: @СuriousBoy Такой код просто не надо писать, ведь в следующей версии даже того же самого компилятора поведение может поменяться. Или даже какой-то флаг компиляции может всё кардинально изменить.

Comment: @СuriousBoy  не определёно на уровне языка. классический пример `i++ + ++i` Компилятор может делать что хочет в данном случае. Раньше был термин точка следования как я уже писал. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F вот на вики. Сейчас чуть-чуть иначе но смысл полностью такой же.

Comment: Хорошо,спасибо. А как понять что может измениться  в новой версии компилятора, изучать документацию(то есть я имею в виду вот что: эти изменения которые могут происходить от версии к версии где то закреплены,описаны?) или тестировать(и удивляться почему не работает код который на другой версии компилятора отрабатывал правильно)?

Comment: @zed Понятно, что такой код лучше не писать, это баловство. Но возник еще вопрос: как понять, что может измениться с выходом новой версии, а что - не может?

Comment: @СuriousBoy Измениться может всё, что чётко не оговорено стандартом. Поэтому надо знать стандарт и тестировать работу под разными компиляторами. Ну и показывать свой код более опытным разработчикам на ревью.

Comment: @Weselton, implementation-defined поведение должно описываться реализацией. Undefined behavior не описывается.

Comment: @СuriousBoy, ко всему вышесказанному добавлю, что для большинства операций приоритет ни как не определяется порядок вычисления аргументов...